How to pre-populate a post/edit template driven form
All, I have a template-driven form that I use to post "blog posts" and the same form to edit the "blog posts." I have searched on Google and YouTube and found a tutorial that explains my attempts, but it's an older version of angular, and I get a lot of type string|null cannot be assigned to string errors
My idea suggests assignment assertion operators, which remove the errors, but the forms do not populate. I read in Stackoverflow about the! operator, which also removes the errors, but still, I can't populate the form. What I expect is that whenever I click on the edit button, the same form I use for posting will populate with the database values (MongoDB).
here are the codes:
create post component 

  post: Post | void | undefined;
  private mode = 'create';
  private postId: string | null | undefined;

  constructor(
    public postService: PostServiceService,
    public route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      if (paramMap.has('postId')) {
        this.mode = 'edit';
        this.postId = paramMap.get('postId');
        this.post = this.postService.getPost(this.post);
      } else {
        this.mode = 'create';
        this.postId = null;
      }
    });
  }

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
post service

 getPost(post?: void | Post | undefined) {
    //return [...this.posts];
    this.http
      .get<{ message: string; posts: any }>('http://localhost:4000/api/posts')
      .pipe(
        map((postData) => {
          return postData.posts.map((post: any) => {
            return {
              title: post.title,
              content: post.content,
              id: post._id,
            };
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe((transformedtData) => {
        this.posts = transformedtData;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app routing

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ListPostComponent },
  { path: 'create', component: CreatePostComponent },
  { path: 'edit/:postId', component: CreatePostComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})


I have found the answer: the error was in the types, the post:Post had to be a public type of the type any so: public post: Post | any.Maybe a future viewer can benefit from this, and i thank all of you for reading this!!!
